# Elaborating on One to Many or Many to One (Can you end a sentence with the word "many")?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests

Full Sentence:

> A Dynamic mapping is sometimes referred to as a One to Many or Many to One translation – implying that in a Dynamic translation, many addresses can appear as one, or **one address can appear as multiple**.

I'm trying to determine a better way of phrasing the bold part. That part of the phrase is elaborating on the concept of a *one to many* translation.

Is it grammatically correct to simply say *... in a Dynamic translation, many addresses can appear as one, or **one address can appear as many**"*

If not, what are some other ways of communicating the same idea with proper grammar?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't end a sentence with the word "many". Both "multiple" and "many" looks fine to me.

Comment: Many is better than multiple.

Comment: Do you mean that one address can repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Correct Usage

"...in a Dynamic translation, many addresses can appear as one, or one address can appear as many."

### Explanation

Writing the clause in this manner maintains *parallel structure*, <sup>1</sup> also referred to as *parallelism*. <sup>2</sup>

This clause also employs *repetition*, "...a major rhetorical strategy for producing emphasis, clarity, amplification, or emotional effect." <sup>3</sup>

---

#### Footnotes

**1.** "Parallel structure means using the same pattern of words to show that two or more ideas have the same level of importance." - [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/1/) (Online Writing Lab)

**2.**

> Parallelism is the presentation of several ideas of equal importance by putting each of them into the same kind of grammatical structure. ... Parallelism provides several benefits: 
>  
>
>  * Clarity. Sentences with parallelism are easier to understand than those without it because a repeated grammatical structure requires less mental process than a series of new structures. 
>  
>
>  * Balance. Parallel structures make it easier for the reader to hold each of the ideas in mind while reading the subsequent ideas.
>  
>
>  * Rhythm. Most readers hear in their minds the words they read. The sound, the musical nature, of the words adds to (or detracts from) the overall reading experience. Parallel structures are more rhythmic than nonparallel structures.
>  
>
>  * Elegance. ... Appropriate use of parallelism provides a texture--even a beauty--to writing that makes it more readable and engaging.

`The parallelism quote immediately above is from the following excellent book, which is available in the original paperback or in a new eBook edition. (I have no affiliation with the author or publisher and the OCLC link goes to the WorldCat.org website, which contains information on where to find books in one's local library.)`

Harris, Robert A. *Writing with Clarity and Style: A Guide to Rhetorical Devices for Contemporary Writers*. Los Angeles, CA: Pyrczak Pub, 2003. **Print**. ISBN-10: 1884585485 ISBN-13: 9781884585487  [OCLC: 50825579](http://www.worldcat.org/title/writing-with-clarity-and-style-a-guide-to-rhetorical-devices-for-contemporary-writers/oclc/50825579)

Harris, Robert A. *Writing with Clarity and Style: A Guide to Rhetorical Devices for Contemporary Writers*. London: Routledge, 2017. **eBook**. ISBN-10: 1351968602 ISBN-13: 9781351968607  [OCLC: 958455216](http://www.worldcat.org/title/writing-with-clarity-and-style-a-guide-to-rhetorical-devices-for-contemporary-writers/oclc/958455216)

**3.** [figures of repetition](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Repetition.htm), *Silva Rhetoricae* (rhetoric.byu.edu), Brigham Young University.

Comment: Wow. Seriously fantastic answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Eddie! I appreciate your kind words. It was a great question btw. :O) ~ Mark